# Dev Tools in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9

I would like to use dev tools like FireBug or the elements built into IE8 for my IE6 testing.

IE9 would provide this.  Before creating an IE9 environment, I thought I would check here.

Do any of you have a solution for this type of problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359) (updated link)

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Comment: seems nice, IE Developer Toolbar functionality is actually quite tragic.

Answer (score 0):

and also you can try IETester 
http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage